# how do i secure a JAX-RS backend that uses Angular js client

Tags: web-services, angularjs, jax-rs, jaas

I'm almost done with a `jax-rs` webservice so currently I'm now working on security part, I have read several articles on implementation of `jaas` and `jdbc` realm roles. some how no one seems to talk about authenticating a user from a remote angular js client.

Assuming i set my roles in `jdbc/realm` and configure my web.xml file ,can i do this?

```
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>+"http://54.200.2.152:8080/service/index.html+"</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>+"http://54.200.2.152:8080/service/error.html+"</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
```

to re-direct to the remote angular-js client? and if i do that,how to i maintain the `js_securitycheck` session id? (meanwhile; sessioning is against rest principles, which is stateless .

Also, is `<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>` preferable for using a remote angular-js client? sending basic64 code and how do I implement this?